# Connection failed in using mysqlconnector ODBC to connect from sql to access

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc

I am trying to connect mysql database in phpmyadmin to the access file. I am using mysqlconnector ODBC for that. Tutorial I am following is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wx910ABixzU)

The problem is that when I give the credentials to connect to database, it gives me error as shown in [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/np4m33x8azvpk7z/Capture.PNG?dl=0) snapshot

I have tried hard to search on internet but failed. What mistake I am doing. I am putting the ftp information of the server there. Is there any database credentials i need to put?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the FTP credentials to connect the MySQL database. You have to use the database credentials. Make sure you have done followings before connecting.

1. Make sure MySQL server is up and running on the HOST IP and PORT.
2. Your MySQL server can accept connections from your IP or use % for
   all IPS
3. Make sure you have a valid USER account

**EDIT**
Or tell us where(local server, internet, IP) the MySQL database is installed. The port number the server is listening on. How you access MySQL server normally.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do have a user account. Am puttting there. in the TCP/IP server, should I put the in some specific format like 192.256.365.41 ? and the port should be default?

Comment: The error is: Lost connection MySql server at reading initial communication packet, system error 0.

Comment: Why do you use port 22? The default is 3306.

Comment: I access the database using ipaddress/phpmyadmin and it asks for the user and password

Comment: It works well using ipaddress/phpmyadmin as a url and putting my database user and its password but my question is, what do i put here that works. i have put both credentials of ftp and ipaddress/phpmyadmin

Comment: try server ip, and 3306 as port number.